# Is it okay to do binary search on an indexed column to get data from a non-indexed column?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, algorithm

I have a large table `users(id, inserttime, ...)`, with index only on `id`. I would like to find list of users who were inserted between a given `start_date` and `finish_date` range.

`User.where(inserttime: start_date..finish_date).find_each`

^This leads to a search which takes a lot of time, since the `inserttime` column is not indexed.

The solution which I came up with is to do find `user.id` for `start_date` and `finish_date` separately by doing a binary search twice on the table using the indexed `id` column.

Then do this to get all the users between `start_id` and `finish_id`:

`User.where(id: start_id..finish_id).find_each`

The binary search function I am using is something like this:

```
def find_user_id_by_date(date)
    low = User.select(:id, :inserttime).first
    high = User.select(:id, :inserttime).last

    low_id = low.id
    high_id = high.id
    
    low_date = low.inserttime
    high_date = high.inserttime

    while(low_id <= high_id)
        mid_id = low_id + ((high_id - low_id) / 2);
        mid = User.select(:id, :inserttime).find_by(id: mid_id)

        # sometimes there can be missing users. Ex: [1,2,8,9,10,16,17,..]
        while mid.nil?
            mid_id = mid_id + 1
            mid = User.select(:id, :inserttime).find_by(id: mid_id)
        end

        if (mid.inserttime < date)
            low_id = mid.id + 1
        elsif (mid.inserttime > date)
            high_id = mid.id - 1
        else
            return mid.id
        end
    end

    # when date = start_date
    return (low_id < high_id) ? low_id + 1 : high_id + 1

    # when date = finish_date
    return (low_id < high_id) ? low_id : high_id + 1
end
```

I am not sure if what I am doing is the right way to deal with this problem or even if my binary search function covers all the cases.

I think the best solution would be to add an index on `inserttime` column but that is sadly not possible.

Comment: how many rows in this table?

Comment: @MattTimmermans there are more than 600 million rows in this table. I have simplified the table schema for SO.

Comment: Are the IDs sequential?

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, since `id` is the primary key which is auto incremented.

Comment: Binary search is OK given the constraints, but you should write that binary search in SQL and execute it on the DB to avoid the many sequential round trips to the server.  I'm not familiar with ruby, on rails or otherwise, so I don't know how you would express that in your stack.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my current search function? Will it be able to cover all cases?

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the best way to do it, but if the IDs are numeric and sequential you could write a query to find the users in between the minimum and maximum user ID:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id BETWEEN [low_id_here] AND [high_id_here];
```

In ActiveRecord:

```
low = User.select(:id, :inserttime).first
high = User.select(:id, :inserttime).last

low_id = low.id
high_id = high.id

User.where('id BETWEEN ? AND ?', low_id, high_id)
```

Comment: `User.where(id: start_id..finish_id).find_each` does exactly that. The main problem is finding `low_id` and `finish_in` in the first place using dates.

Comment: Could you do SELECT MIN(id) FROM users where insertdate > [start_date]; SELECT MAX(id) FROM users where insertdate < [end_date]; to get the start and end IDs?

Comment: I wish I could do `SELECT id FROM users WHERE inserttime BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` but since the `inserttime` column is not indexed, doing any operation on the it will take quite some time to get the results since the table is pretty large.

Comment: Are you able create new tables in this database? You could create a table that has a column that stores each days date and the min and max ID that was generated on that day. You could back fill it and then keep it up to date going forward. I would only suggest something like this if the index is completely out of the question and this is a query that is executed often. I'm just trying to think of a way to avoid all of the round trips to the DB by using the binary search in Ruby.

Comment: Luckily this query is not executed very often and that is the only reason why I am not willing to create an index. For the same reason making another table for this does not make sense to me as of now. I guess I'll go ahead with doing a binary search using rails even after knowing the cost. Thanks!